# How to use NSURL with relative path?

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

So, I'm building a command line tool in Swift that takes a filepath as an argument.
I check if the filepath exists, else I throw an error.
When I use an absolute path, everything works as it should.
When I use a relative path, it doesn't.

**code:**

```
  let pwdURL = URL(string: "file://" + FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
  print("pwdURL: ", pwdURL ?? "no pwdURL")
  let pathURL = URL(string: path, relativeTo: pwdURL)
  print("pathURL: ", pathURL ?? "no pathURL")

  do {
    let _ = try pathURL?.checkResourceIsReachable()
  }
    catch {
    print(error)
    throw ValidationError("\(path) Is not a valid path.")
  }
```

**command:**

From the `/Users/myUser/Projects/myProject` folder, in the terminal.

```
  swift run myProject ../../Downloads/myFile.pdf
```

**output:**

```
  pwdURL:  file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myProject
  pathURL:  ../../Downloads/myFile.pdf -- file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myProject
  
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “myFile.pdf” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=../../Downloads/myFile.pdf -- file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myProject, NSFilePath=/Users/Downloads/myFile.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fad39d0c280 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
  Error: ../../Downloads/myFile.pdf Is not a valid path.
```

I was expecting it to look for `/Users/myUser/Downloads/myFile.pdf`, because that is a valid path from where I type the command in the terminal. Also, when I look at the output from the pathURL (`../../Downloads/myFile.pdf -- file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myProject`), it looks like this would resolve to the correct path?
But as you can see, there is an error because it is looking for `/Users/Downloads/myFile.pdf`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required that the `relativeTo` parameter end in a `/` for this to work the way you're expecting. From the [NSURL docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417949-init) (emphasis added):

> This method allows you to create a URL relative to a base path or URL. For example, if you have the URL for a folder on disk and the name of a file within that folder, you can construct a URL for the file by providing the folder’s URL as the base path (**with a trailing slash**) and the filename as the string part.

So what you need here is:

```
let pwdURL = URL(string: "file://" + FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath + "/")
```

But I would actually do it this way:

```
let pwdURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
```

or:

```
let pwdURL = Process().currentDirectoryURL
```

I typically find it easier to do this using `appendingPathComponent`, which is a bit easier to use correctly:

```
let pathURL = pwdURL.appendingPathComponenent(path)
```

The difference it that this will leave the `../..` in the path rather than resolving those away, so it does depend on which you want.

Comment: Another option is to create the base URL with `URL(fileURLWithPath: ..., isDirectory: true)`

Comment: heh; I was just double checking how to do that correctly.